# use fork (process) instead of pthread to acieve the same

Tags: c, pointers, process, pthreads, fork

I have achieved concurrency with the following code by creating parallel threads. However, how should I go about using fork() to create child processes and do the same job as done by the main() below? I want to avoid creating any thread.

```
struct function_args
    {
        pthread_t thread;
        char *command;
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        while (1)
            {
                if (mode == 1)
                    printf("$> ");
    
                if ((nread = getline(&line, &linecap, in)) > 0)
                {
                    char *command;
                    int commands_num = 0;
                    struct function_args args[BUFF_SIZE];
    
                    // remove newline character
                    if (line[nread - 1] == '\n')
                        line[nread - 1] = '\0';
    
                    char *temp = line;
    
                    while ((command = strsep(&temp, "&")) != NULL)
                        if (command[0] != '\0')
                        {
                            args[commands_num++].command = strdup(command);
                            if (commands_num >= BUFF_SIZE)
                                break;
                        }
    
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < commands_num; i++)
                        if (pthread_create(&args[i].thread, NULL, &parseInput, &args[i]) != 0)
                            printError();
    
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < commands_num; i++)
                    {
                        if (pthread_join(args[i].thread, NULL) != 0)
                            printError();
                        if (args[i].command != NULL)
                            free(args[i].command);
                    }
                }
                else if (feof(in) != 0)
                {
                    atexit(clean);
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    // EOF
                }
            }
    
            return 0;
    }
```

I am aware that `pid = fork()` returns a processid which is 0 for the child and >0 for the parent. However, in the for loops below where I am handling multiple `argv`, I am not sure how to translate my main() to do so.

Comment: Just so you know forking is way more expensive than multi-threading. Not sure why you would want to downgrade your code to that.

Comment: Pthreads require OS level support. Just to explore another mutual exclusion approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on what you're doing. In general terms you could do something like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < commands_num; i++)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        parseInput(&args[i]);
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid == -1)
        printError();
    else
        args[i].thread = pid;
}
```

The children processes work independently of the parent and go about completing their task, so probably there's will be no need to do the equivalent of `pthread_join()` here in which case would be `waitpid()`, unless the parent process has to wait for their product to do something with it.

And speaking of which, once the processes are forked, they no longer share the same memory space, so transiting information between the children and the parent might be a challenge in itself. If you're just printing stuff to `stdout` you're set to go, otherwise you'll have to figure out pipes to make parent and children communicate.

Another alternative to using system native threads (or pthreads in particular) is to use some green thread library such as [libdill](http://libdill.org/), theoretically it will enable multi-threading even in systems that don't support native multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What does the last statement do? args[i].thread = pid;

Comment: I gave it a quick shot and have some confusion about invocation.
Suppose args[0] has the string "cd test" and after fork(), the pid gets an integer value, then the pid ==0 part is not being reached and I am not able to invoke functions from there on. Should there be function calls after the args[i].thread = pid; part ?

Comment: The last statement is just for consistency with your code, I'm saving the child process PID into `args[i].thread`. It's likely that you wont need it though.

Comment: After a successful `fork()` the process is cloned and `pid` is `0` for the child and the child's PID to the parent, so in a sense `if (pid == 0)` will be both true and false, true to the child and false to the parent, so the child will run the code inside it and the parent won't.